# knockout mapping of properties not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

The mapping does not seem to work properly:

```
 @{ var jsonData = new HtmlString(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)); }

    var initialData = @jsonData;
```

--->  At that stage, initialData contains the correct data in jSon format

```
    var viewModel;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData, viewModel);
```

---> Here, the viewModel contains all the properties. In Chrome debugger, if I type viewModel.Products (which is an array property), it is found and seems to be properly mapped.

However, if I do viewModel.Products[0], that returns 'undefined', which is weird because the array actually contains 4 items (I can see it in the jSon data).

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be an observable property after you've mapped it, so you access it as if it were a function(which it is):

```
viewModel.Products()[0];
```

Comment: yes, that works. It feels strange to me to work with an array this way, I'll get use to it.  Another question, how do I access the value of the item using the syntax data-bind="foreach: Products". That's for looping through the array's item, but how do I access the actual item ?

Comment: The item is just available to you inside the loop, so you just data-bind to any of the properties of the item directly data-bind="text: nameOfItemProperty".

Comment: that's the problem, I don't have a property. The array is an array of strings with no property name

Comment: $data is what you want then.